# How to enable customization textbox in CA304000 screen?

Tags: acumatica

I adding some customization field in CA304000 ( Finance ->Cash Managerment -> Transaction) but these text field automaticaly disable. [image]

Can you guy help me please ?!

Comment: Can you include the code definition for your fields in your question?

Comment: There is no code for this field. It's just the Data Class of the field (For example: UsrTNVName we have: [PXDBString(60)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Người nhận/nộp tiền:")]. It didn't happen to be disable in another screen. I think this CA304000 Transaction screen have the page load function to disable textbox at initiate. Either you can tell me how to disable it or tell me how to create event to enable these new added textbox step by step. I've tried add the enable in the properties tab but It didn't work. Thank for your support, please do step by step (with image is perfect), I'm new to this !

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the `CATranEntry` graph in `CAAdj_RowSelected` you will see the entire row is marked as enabled = false (`PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(sender, adj, false);`)

You need to extend this graph and CAAdj_RowSelected to enable your fields with similar logic found in the graph already. For example there is already a check for determining if the transaction is released:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CAAdj.curyControlAmt>(sender, adj, adjNotReleased);
```

You will use this same syntax for your custom fields with something like this

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<CAAdj.usrTNVName>(sender, adj, adjNotReleased);
```

Use the same logic found in the base graph for how adjNotReleased gets set and use it in your extension.